# Building Flexbuilder projects in ant

Tags: apache-flex, ant, build, flexbuilder

I'm using Flexbuilder as an IDE, and I'm working on automating the process of building my application.

In the process of setting up the ant build file, I noticed that there's no way to call the project using the list of dependancies that Flex builder stores - each library or library project has to be added to the flex compiler commands manually. This creates an enormous burden on the developers to update the build scripts, and makes the build process very uncomfortably fragile.

Is there an option or third party project that addresses this? Failing that, is it possible to build using Flex builder's process via command line?

Comment: This question has come up before, but it doesn't seem to be answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000/building-flex-projects-in-ant-nant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be of use.

[automating component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395860/how-can-i-automate-the-building-of-a-flex-component-library/1398235#1398235)